# Is it possible to merge two sets such that all references to both sets will refer to the new?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, say I have two sets A and B, along with multiple references to both sets.

**Is there a way to merge the two sets A and B such that all references to both sets will refer to the newly merged set**? If possible, what will be the runtime?

```
A = {1,3}
B = {2,4}
aRef1 = A
aRef2 = A
bRef1 = B
bRef2 = B
MergeSets(A,B)
# Now, whenever I use any of (A, B, aRef1, aRef2, bRef1, bRef2) 
# they refer to the same set which will be {1,2,3,4}
```

Thank you

**EDIT:**

Some people have been asking why I wanted to do this, and here's a copy/paste of one of my replies below:

> So I know I can do A.update(B), to merge B into A, but then I'd have
>   to iterate through all references to B and set them to refer to A. **I
>   was asking so I can avoid these extra iterations**. I could supply more
>   context to get a new approach to my specific scenario, but I'm more
>   curious to know if this is possible in python as a general case.

Further, it looks like my question has been answered and the verdict is that this is not possible. Thanks again everybody :)

Comment: You want `aRef1` to see the union of `A` and `B` after the merge? If so, why? There might be more context that suggests another approach.

Comment: @doctorlove So I know I can do A.update(B), to merge B into A, but then I'd have to iterate through all references to B and set them to refer to A. I was asking so I can avoid these extra iterations. I could supply more context to get a new approach to my specific scenario, but I'm more curious to know if this is possible in python as a general case.

Comment: You could write your own class for sets which would act (roughly) in the way that you want. An idea is that either an object holds its own data or it points to one that holds its data (either directly or through a chain). Once you merge two set objects, the old sets will point to the new in a way that (if properly written) is transparent to the user. Getting the details correct would be tricky, but doable.

Comment: The only way to change what object a name refers to is to reassign to that name; a "3rd-party" operation cannot do that.

Comment: There's an off-chance you might want to look up "union find". There's a library or two for Python, but they don't seem heavily used. The "union" operation basically says (in this context) I have these two sets A and B, but from now on when I refer to B, I really mean A (or whatever A really means). And "find" follows those links to find the single item that currently represents everything that's in the same union as the object you call it for.

Comment: I am thinking: is there a real case scenario in which this operation would be useful? I am struggling to find one possible use of this method. Anyway I really like the question apart of its pratical use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They currently *all* are referencing to their respective sets `A` or `B`, according to the assignments you've made. For instance in the case of `bRef1`:

```
id(B)
# 112140097128

id(bRef1)
# 112140097128
```

The fact that the original `set` is modified or not by modifying the new sets depends on the kind of operations you perform. If you perform an *in-place* operation, for instance:

```
bRef1 |= {5}
```

And check the original variable `B`, you can see that indeed it has been updated:

```
print(B)
# {2, 4, 5}
```

---

Though when you merge both sets, unless you also perform an in-place operation and hence explicitly update one of the two sets, you will be creating a new object:

```
new_set = aRef2 | bRef2

id(new_set)
# 112140098248
```

---

But still, in the case you update in-place one of the sets `A` or `B` by merging it with the other, given that *you've started out with `2` different objects*, there is no way of changing that into all sets referencing the same object.

Comment: This is not wrong - it's a very good outlining of the behaviour of sets, especially with repsect to references/objects in memory! But I think the OP wasn't asking to understand this behaviour (I think they know that already), they're wanting to know if there's a way to merge A & B, such that all references to A or B now point to this new object. (e.g. `A |= B; B |= A` would mean all references point to the same _set_, but that's still two different objects in memory. `A |= B; B = A` would mean all references to `A` would be good, as would `B`, but it wouldn't help with `bref1` and `bref2`).

Comment: Yes, that is kind of inferred from my answer answer bu I might not have made it clear enough. Updated @tim

Comment: Yeah, that edit at the end makes it really clear, and is quite a good way of explaining why very briefly!

Answer (score 1):

Python references are passed by value, so you can't reassign bindings passed as parameters to a function. An alternative here would be to mutate the objects passed to your function.

```py
In [35]: A = {1,3}
    ...: B = {2,4}
    ...: aRef1 = A
    ...: aRef2 = A
    ...: bRef1 = B
    ...: bRef2 = B

In [36]: def merge_sets(a, b):
    ...:     for el in b:
    ...:         a.add(el)
    ...:     for el in a:
    ...:         b.add(el)

In [37]: merge_sets(A, B)

In [38]: [id(s) for s in (A, B, aRef1, aRef2, bRef1, bRef2)]
Out[38]:
[140333907731848,
 140333907731176,
 140333907731848,
 140333907731848,
 140333907731176,
 140333907731176]

In [39]: [s for s in (A, B, aRef1, aRef2, bRef1, bRef2)]
Out[39]:
[{1, 2, 3, 4},
 {1, 2, 3, 4},
 {1, 2, 3, 4},
 {1, 2, 3, 4},
 {1, 2, 3, 4},
 {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

`merge_sets` executes in linear time.

Comment: Your idea perhaps captures some of what OP wants -- but there really is no reason to use `for` loops to compute unions. Why not `a.update(b)` followed by `b.update(a)`?

Comment: Strong claim. The OP is obviously a novice with Python — there is pedagogical utility in being as explicit as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
A = {1,3}
B = {2,4}
aRef1 = A
aRef2 = A
bRef1 = B
bRef2 = B
```

if you want all the six objects to refer to the same set **but not the same object**:

```
A |= B
B |= A 

print(A, id(A))
print(aRef1, id(aRef1))
print(aRef2, id(aRef2))
print(B, id(B))
print(bRef1, id(bRef1))
print(bRef2, id(bRef2))


#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2668549913736 (1°object)
#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2668549913736 (1°object)
#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2668549913736 (1°object)
#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2668549967944 (2°object)
#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2668549967944 (2°object)
#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2668549967944 (2°object)
```

if you want all the six objects to refer to the same set **but not the same object** using `mergeList` function:

```
def mergeList(A, B):
    A |= B
    B |= A

mergeList(A, B)
print(A, id(A))
print(aRef1, id(aRef1))
print(aRef2, id(aRef2))
print(B, id(B))
print(bRef1, id(bRef1))
print(bRef2, id(bRef2))


#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2668549913736 (1°object)
#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2668549913736 (1°object)
#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2668549913736 (1°object)
#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2668549967944 (2°object)
#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2668549967944 (2°object)
#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2668549967944 (2°object)
```

if you want all the six objects to refer to the same set and **the same object**:

```
A |= B
B = A
bRef1 = B
bRef2 = B

print(A, id(A))
print(aRef1, id(aRef1))
print(aRef2, id(aRef2))
print(B, id(B))
print(bRef1, id(bRef1))
print(bRef2, id(bRef2))


#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2538372611208 (same object)
#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2538372611208 (same object)
#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2538372611208 (same object)
#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2538372611208 (same object)
#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2538372611208 (same object)
#{1, 2, 3, 4} 2538372611208 (same object)
```

using `mergeList` would be a little tricky to have all the variables reference to the same object

Comment: OP wants for `MegeSet` to do the rebindings automatically (and presumably would want that even for references which are in embedded in lists and not just named variables)

Comment: @JohnColeman you're right. It would be a little tricky to do so